# Does the dot3StatsInternalMacReceiveErrors counter include Vlan mismatches

Tags: switchport, ieee-802.3x, drops, statistics, counters

I am wondering if the dot3StatsInternalMacReceiveErrors counter includes VLAN mismatches, i.e. Discards due to VLAN mismatch. http://oid-info.com/get/1.3.6.1.2.1.10.7.2.1.16 only explicitly lists `dot3StatsAlignmentErrors` and `dot3StatsFCSErrors` as alternatives... this is for a chip from `Broadcom`. Any input is appreciated!

**(ASN.1 notation)**

```
{iso(1) identified-organization(3) dod(6) internet(1) mgmt(2) mib-2(1) transmission(10) dot3(7) dot3StatsTable(2) dot3StatsEntry(1) dot3StatsInternalMacReceiveErrors(16)}
```

**(dot notation)**

```
1.3.6.1.2.1.10.7.2.1.16
```

**(OID-IRI notation)**

```
/ISO/Identified-Organization/6/1/2/1/10/7/2/1/16
```

**Description:**

```
dot3StatsInternalMacReceiveErrors OBJECT-TYPE
SYNTAX Counter32
MAX-ACCESS read-only
STATUS current
DESCRIPTION "A count of frames for which reception on a
particular interface fails due to an internal
MAC sublayer receive error. A frame is only
counted by an instance of this object if it is
not counted by the corresponding instance of
either the dot3StatsFrameTooLongs object, the
dot3StatsAlignmentErrors object, or the
dot3StatsFCSErrors object.
The precise meaning of the count represented by
an instance of this object is implementation-
specific. In particular, an instance of this
object may represent a count of receive errors
on a particular interface that are not
otherwise counted.
Discontinuities in the value of this counter can
occur at re-initialization of the management
system, and at other times as indicated by the
value of ifCounterDiscontinuityTime."
REFERENCE "[IEEE 802.3 Std.], 30.3.1.1.15,
aFramesLostDueToIntMACRcvError."
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*dot3StatsInternalMacReceiveErrors* refers to framing errors only - as stated, misalignment, FCS errors, giants, runts. A VLAN mismatch is not an error on the MAC level in that respect.

Nitpicking, VLAN tags belong to 802.1 while the general framing belongs to 802.3.

Comment: Thanks Zac, is there any counter you know about that would report if the L2 learning is disabled and hence a frame (with a new SMAC) gets discarded?